# Robolectric 3 : Load test specific resource

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I'm using Robolectric 3 and I'm trying to load some resources that are in my `test/res/` folder.

Here is my file hierarchy :

```
project/
|-src/
|--main/
|---AndroidManifest.xml
|---res/
|----raw/
|-----prod.json
|--test/
|---java/
|----com.app/
|-----CustomTestRunner.java
|-----Mytest.java
|---res/
|----raw/
|-----test.json
```

I would like in `MyTest.java` to do something like

```
RuntimeEnvironment.application.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test);
```

but i don't want to override all my "standard" `res/` folder because i also need the `prod.json` file inside of my test.

Any idea of how to do such things ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of putting the json in src/test/res/raw you might want to put it in src/test/resources/

and then you can use it ( with the latest build plugin and latest AS ) via getResource

Be aware that there is a bug in older versions - you need to use AS from canary channel: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=136013

Comment: I've found that i need to use resources/ folder and not res/ (or assets/) i adjusted my test to load a file from the classloader instead of using the android raw loading.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue and tracked at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=136013

Some report that this is fixed with gradle android plugin version 1.3 but not for android studio. A fix is planed for Android Studio 1.3 but someone posted a workaround which works with both tools in version 1.2

Here the code with a small modification because I could not find the used StringUtils class:

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
  def variants = android.applicationVariants.collect()

  tasks.withType(Test) { task ->
    try {
        variants.each { variant ->
            def buildTypeName = variant.buildType.name.capitalize()

            def productFlavorNames = variant.productFlavors.collect { it.name.capitalize() }
            if (productFlavorNames.isEmpty()) {
                productFlavorNames = [""]
            }
            def productFlavorName = productFlavorNames.join('')
            def flavor = uncapitalize(productFlavorName)

            def variationName = "${productFlavorName}${buildTypeName}"

            if (task.name.contains(variationName)) {
                def variationPath = variant.buildType.name;

                if (productFlavorName != null && !productFlavorName.isEmpty()) {
                    variationPath = uncapitalize(productFlavorName) + "/" + variationPath
                }

                def copyTestResourcesTask = project.tasks.create("copyTest${variationName}Resources", Copy)
                copyTestResourcesTask.from("${projectDir}/src/test/resources")
                copyTestResourcesTask.into("${buildDir}/intermediates/classes/test/${variationPath}")

                // Makes the test task depend on the copy test resource variation task
                task.dependsOn(copyTestResourcesTask)

                variants.remove(variant)

                throw new Exception("Break") // Breaking the loop
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {} // Just drop the exception
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In gradle you can define your test res adding your standard res.

Something like this:

```
android{

sourceSets {

    test {
        res.srcDirs = ['src/test/res', 'src/main/res']

        }
    }
}
```